# Could you tell me a simple clear project structure to have AngularJS component in VueJS project?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js

Actually, I have two projects.
One is `AngularJS` and another one is `VueJS`.
I want to use the `AngularJS` components that were implemented many years ago in the `VueJS` project.

Thank you

Comment: For this, you have to go for tutorials.

Comment: You can look at this :[How to Migrate from AngularJS to Vue](https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-migrate-from-angularjs-to-vue-4a1e9721bea8)